# Offline access to FB graph api from Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do you query facebook's graph api via the javascript sdk for users that have allready given you permissions (offline access) and whose auth data you have stored, but who are not currently logged in to facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, you can in fact do so. You can use FB.api calls and include the access token at the end of the URL with ?access_token=

Comment: Isn't it rather insecure to use that, though?

Comment: How so? It seems to me that the only person who could see that access token is the user it belongs to.

Comment: the calls are over https now right? so I think Finster is correct that only the user who's token it is would see it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the code you'd need to actually do it, but I think one of the key elements to this would be logging in to the SDK as an application, rather than a Facebook User, as detailed in the documentation @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

Have you got an example query that you'd like to make with the SDK?

Comment: Let's say I want to display something like the user's number of friends every time they access my page. I would like to only have the user have to log in to facebook the first time they use the page. After that I should be able to use the javascript sdk to dynamically make queries using the auth_data that I received from the first log-in. But so far I can only seem to make queries from the server using the auth data, or from the client after having the user log in to facebook.